# Swift: UIPanGestureRecognizer How to tell if use dragged finger outside screen

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

Swift iOS app using UIPanGestureRecognizer:

`.state = .Ended` is fired when user finishes a pan gesture by lifting the finger off the screen. This is successful pan for me.

However, the same happens when the user drags their finger off the screen, which is an unsuccessful pan for me but how to distinguish it from the former?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't distinguish between the gesture ending because the user lifted the finger and the gesture ending because the finger went off the edge of the screen. You've already deduced that, quite correctly. So you will have to settle for what you *can* do.

When the gesture ends, look at the location of the finger. (The gesture recognizer will happily tell you this.) If it's at the edge of the screen, or perhaps even within a couple of points of the edge of the screen, you'll just have to *assume* arbitrarily that this means the user dragged "out of bounds".

Comment: If the recognizer reports a useful velocity when in phase `.Ended`, one could use the velocity to improve the detection of a drag off screen. I haven't checked whether it reports a useful velocity.

Comment: hmm... thats not ideal, hoping someone will come up with a better solution.

Comment: Well, don't blame the messenger. You asked if there's a way to tell the difference between those two things; there isn't. As Rob says, you might make a guess based on the velocity of the finger at the time the gesture ends. But basically you're trying to draw a distinction that just isn't in the repertory.